# When calling TypeScript function from html it loops more time

Tags: angular

In angular I created hasError function to cover all validation cases in my component.
when i tried to use it in html i found that it entered in loop more times
and after that it fires validation.

I need to know why this loop accured.

my typescript function

```
  hasError(input) {
    if (input == "email") {
      if (this.loginForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')) return 'Validation.emailRequired';
      if (this.loginForm.controls['email'].hasError('email')) return 'Validation.invalidEmail';

      else return '';
    }
    if (input == "password") {
      if (this.loginForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')) return 'Validation.passwordRequired';

      else return '';
    }
  }
```

my HTML

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
          <input matInput [placeholder]="'Login.Email'|translate"  formControlName ="email">
          <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid">
              {{hasError('email')|translate}} // i'm using it here 

          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Its not a loop, your app has to update view, for that it runs change detections, (on browser events, like click, input, etc. Timers, Ajax calls) to check updates in the view bindings. When those happen your `hasError()` will run

Comment: What? The counter will increase every time this method is called